# Sample of one, extermination of fruit flies and daily life challenges

Tags: probability, self-study, statistical-significance, small-sample

**First of all**, I'm very well aware that a sample of one is **ridiculous** in any normal scenario in the domain of statistics, and I know that any rationale from this would probably only have **esoteric** value, if even relevant to statistics at all. I'm sorry if this question is misplaced, but in the best of worlds I hope that it could provide some interdisciplinary fundamental understanding that could be applied to the experience of, for example, a regular life.

**Daily life scenario**
I currently have a small problem with a small population of fruit flies in my apartment, and in an attempt to resolve this I resorted to the classic solution with a glass of water with some vinegar and detergent. Kind of. Because I did not have vinegar at home, I instead used three other fluids I found in my refrigerator, and prepared three different glasses with each one of these fluids, together with a base of water and some detergent.

They have now been placed on location in the window together with the plants that the fruit flies hang around with, and much to my disappointment, the extermination hasn't gone to well so far.

Only one fruit fly has fallen victim for my traps, and this is of course in only one of the samples.

Now, imagine that I now abort the experiment, only to wake up tomorrow and realise that the world overnight has been invaded by the same kind of fruit flies. Somehow the world leaders know about my experiments in fruit fly extermination, and give me the responsibility to end the plague. And as a strange twist of fate, the only options I'm given is to use the same strategy with the glasses, using the same options of households fluids I had, and due to the acuteness and severity of the invasion I can only choose to use one of these fluids, due to that it immediately has to be mass-produced, taking the rest of the worlds production resources in claim.

Now what should I do? Well, even if the data from my study is ridiculously limited, the only indication I have is that sample B at least have one victim. I don't know if this is only due to coincidence, if the other two actually are repelling the fruit flies or if even sample B is repelling where the one victim I had just accidentally fell down sitting on the rim of the glass laughing at my futile attempts at mass murder.

Assuming that we have no other information about the efficiency of the three different samples, my only choice is to choose sample B, since the only indication I have is that this sample at least seem to have some potential, while those indications is zero for the other two samples.

**The question**
How should I feel about this decision when the orders go out to the world leaders to produce sample B? How should I think around the soundness of my decision? Could I just as well have rolled a three-sided dice, or does the extremely limited data actually provide some reassurance?

*Is there any theory in statistics considering extremely limited samples like this scenario?* Is is simply one in three that this is the best option, or could it somehow be considered an educated and rational guess considering the data we actually have? If going away from the domain of rigours science and into the regular life of a human, we can probably see that an individual could be subjected of these extremely small sample sizes on a regular basis, for example strategies on job interviews, criteria for choosing mates, or 
other rare selections where humans even often seem to stick to a "winning" concept even with extremely small sample sizes, taking the "safe" before the "unknown".

**Is it that this question have no place in statistics, but have some relevance in other domains, as maybe something like predicate logic, where the sample size of one actually is significant, considering the circumstances?**